# Primefaces fullPage Layout toggle not working

Tags: jquery-ui, primefaces, uibutton

Here is code directly copied from the primefaces full page demo

```
<p:layout fullPage="true">  

<p:layoutUnit position="north" size="100" header="Top" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">  
    <h:outputText value="North unit content." />  
</p:layoutUnit>  

<p:layoutUnit position="south" size="100" header="Bottom" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">  
    <h:outputText value="South unit content." />  
</p:layoutUnit>  

<p:layoutUnit position="west" size="200" header="Left" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">  
    <h:outputText value="West unit content." />  
</p:layoutUnit>  

<p:layoutUnit position="east" size="200" header="Right" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true" effect="drop">  
    <h:outputText value="Right unit content." />  
</p:layoutUnit>  

<p:layoutUnit position="center">  
    <h:form>  
        This fullPage layout consists of five different layoutUnits which are resizable and closable by default.  

    </h:form>  
</p:layoutUnit>
```

When I run this code the closable and collapsible buttons are there but do nothing. Any idea what might be causing this?

Answer (score 4):

your should use h:form for each layoutunit.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things:
1) Are you closing "p:layout"? 
2) Careful using h:form, maybe you are using it around p:layout, if so, erase it.
3) Do you have any error messages?